# RegEx for matching specific phone numbers

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to see if a string matches my country's phone number format, which is the area code (two digits that may or may not be preceded by a 0 and might also be between parenthesis) followed by 8 or 9 digits in which there may be an dash character before the 4 last digits.
These are some valid formats:

```rb
'00 00000000'
'000-000000000'
'000 00000-0000'
'00 0000-0000'
'(00) 0000-0000'
'(000) 000000000'
```

So far this is the working expression I have:

```rb
p = /0?\d{2}\s?-?\s?\d{4,5}\s?-?\s?\d{4}/
```

I tried to use a conditional to see if the area code is inside parenthesis with `/?(\() 0?\d{2}\)|0?\d{2} \s?-?\s?\d{4,5}\s?-?\s?\d{4}/` but got the `(repl):1: target of repeat operator is not specified: /?(\() 0?\d{2}\)|0?\d{2} \s?-?\s?\d{4,5}\s?-?\s?\d{4}` error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you include some examples where the phone number contains parentheses?

Comment: When you say 9 digits, do you mean 4 digits, dash, then 4 digits?

Comment: Just added the examples.

Comment: It may be 4 digits, dash and then 4 digits, but it also could be 5 digits, dash and the 4 digits.

Comment: I've posted an answer which takes care of the parentheses problem, feel free to check it out

Comment: Have you considered combine multiple simple patterns via `|` rather than having one very complex one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use the following regular expression.

```
R = /
    \A            # match beginning of string
    (?:           # begin a non-capture group
      \(0?\d{2}\) # match '(' then an optional `0` then two digits then ')'
    |             # or
      0?\d{2}     # match an optional `0` then two digits
    )             # end the non-capture group
    (?:           # begin a non-capture group
      [ ]+        # match one or more spaces
    |             # or
      -           # match a hyphen
    )             # end the non-capture group
    \d{4,5}       # match 4 or 5 digits
    -?            # optionally match a hyphen
    \d{4}         # match 4 digits
    \z            # match end of string
    /x            # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
arr = [
  '00 00000000',
  '000-000000000',
  '000 00000-0000',
  '00 0000-0000',
  '(00) 0000-0000',
  '(000) 000000000',
  '(000 000000000',
  '(0000) 000000000'
]

arr.map { |s| s.match? R }
  #=> [true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false]
```

The regex is conventionally written as follows.

```
R = /\A(?:\(0?\d{2}\)|0?\d{2})(?: +|-)\d{4,5}-?\d{4}\z/
```

This should be changed as follows if the leading digits cannot equal zero. (If, for example, `'001-123456789'` and `'(12)-023456789'` are invalid.)

```
R = /\A(?:\(0?[1-9]\d\)|0?\[1-9]\d)(?: +|-)[1-9]\d{3,4}-?\d{4}\z/
```

Answer (score 4):

Do not validate phone numbers with regular expressions. I bet you do not want to rule out those occasionally typing 2 consequent spaces or something.

Instead, filter out all the non-digits and leading zeroes, and then validate. Like this:

```
number.gsub(/\D+/, '').gsub(/\A0+/) =~ /\d{8,9}/
```

I am not sure it would suit your needs out of the box, but I bet you’ve got the point. After all, `[000]1234   56789` is an understandable phone number.

Comment: Thank you! That's a great idead, I'll sure do that.

Comment: mudsie, I believe you meant `.gsub(/\A0+/, '')`. This does not tell us whether a string represents a valid phone number, but isn't that the idea? For example, `"Something like 99.473218% of Rubiests use snake case for names of variables and methods.".gsub(/\D+/, '').gsub(/\A0+/, '') =~ /\d{8,9}/ #=> 0`. I confirmed that by phoning that number and heard no ringtone.

Comment: Doesn't this also not match the requirements because only the single leading 0 should be ignored?

Comment: If the requirement is to scary users, or to play regex golf, then yes, the above does not work. If the goal is to validate the user’s input, than it is the only way to go. Because when they reject the number I entered, because they have a sophisticated regex there, you know, I close the page. Forever. After all, 555- numbers would pass, while they are surely invalid.

Comment: But if it accepts invalid input and then they can't call you because they stored an invalid number... that's also annoying

Comment: The chance I would occasionally swap two digits is likely 1M times more probable than I would enter the Shakespeare's sonnet there.

Comment: The same applies for emails, addresses etc. I was living at Street, 1bis,  building 1/2-3, app. 5-5 (do not ask) and guess how many food delivery forms accepted that.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I agree. With that perspective I would just strip non-digits and verify it's non-empty. Stripping leading zeros is possibly destructive.

Answer (score 2):

There might be several ways to validate these numbers. One way would be that, we write all our possible phone numbers, then write an expression for it. Maybe, similar to:

```
[0-9]{2,3}(\s|-)[0-9]{4,5}-?[0-9]{3,4}
```

#### Test

```
re = /[0-9]{2,3}(\s|-)[0-9]{4,5}-?[0-9]{3,4}/m
str = '\'00 00000000\'
\'000-000000000\'
\'000 00000-0000\'
\'00 0000-0000\''

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

#### Demo

This snippet is just to show the capturing groups and that the expression might be valid:

```js
const regex = /[0-9]{2,3}(\s|-)[0-9]{4,5}-?[0-9]{3,4}/gm;
const str = `'00 00000000'
'000-000000000'
'000 00000-0000'
'00 0000-0000'`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fr7TRG/1/).

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]

---

#### Edit 1:

In case of `()`, we want to add two negative lookbehind to our initial expression. Maybe, [similar to this](https://regex101.com/r/EdGdfE/1/):

```
\(?[0-9]{2,3}\)?(\s|-)[0-9]{4,5}-?[0-9]{3,4}
```

[image]

Comment: Leading `[0-9]{2,3}` would match `999` which must be ruled out according to OP.

Comment: Yes, but if I put `0?\d{2}` it should do it, right?

Comment: I just added more examples using parenthesis

Comment: No, the question has not been changed. Examples were added, but the statement itself stays as it was.

Comment: @aplneto should do exactly what? This is not any better than your original approach and it has nothing to do with the real question about parentheses.

Comment: Hi @Emma, it's almos this but it can't match a string with just open or closing parenthesis like `(00 0000-0000`. Also the area code must be an optional '0' followed by two digits.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, I was talking about the area code format. That this `0?\d{2}` should match the format I explained right?

Comment: @Emma It is, but this format should not be valid. What I want to validade in the expression is if there is an opening parenthesis before the area code, there should also be a closing one.
Like `(0000000000` should not be valid, but `0000000000` and `(00)000000000` should.

Comment: `'(000) 000000000'.match? re #=> false` and `'(000 000000000'.match? re #=> true`. Unfortunately, both are incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

My answer addresses your [conditional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) idea for the optional parenthesis.
Ruby supports conditionals since v2.0. The [syntax](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/using-conditionals-inside-ruby-regular-expressions/) is `(?(A)X|Y)`: If A is true, X else Y.

- Put an [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) containing an opening parenthesis at start:
  `^(\()?`
- Later anywhere in the pattern check if it succeeded:
  `(?(1)\) |[ -])`
  If success: require a closing `)` followed by space
  `|` else: `[ -]` space or dash.

So the whole pattern with conditional could be

```
^(\()?0?\d{2}(?(1)\) |[ -])\d{4,5}[ -]?\d{4}$
```

See the [demo at Rubular](https://rubular.com/r/WXQBmX0NwVFzNV) or [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9JBc8Z/1). Adjust further to your needs.

An alternative to use alternation `(?:\(abc\)|abc)` which @CarySwoveland answered already but @AlekseiMatiushkin's answer surely will make life easier I think.

Comment: The conditional expression is new to me and certainly a worthwhile addition to my toolbelt. Considering that it is so potentially useful, and that Ruby v2.0 has been out for so long, I'm surprised that I've not seen it used before here at SO.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this unless you know you are working in a very, *very* limited scope e.g.

- The numbers are being passed to a system that only accepts a specific format so you know that these exact formats and no others will work
- The numbers are just read by a human, so you can let them figure it out and don't have to validate anything

Otherwise you should use a robust library like https://github.com/mobi/telephone_number (inspired by Google's [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber))